# Installation of FSL failled : computer crashes during installation of FSL on Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 11

Tags: software-installation, crash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to download FSL on Ubuntu 20.04 on my Windows 11 computer following the instructions from: https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation/Windows.

After running python "/mnt/c/Users//Downloads/fslinstaller.py"
the downloader starts and downloads miniconda, then FSL.

The download bar stays stuck at 100% for several minutes and the computer crashes every time: a blue screen appears with the message "your device has encountered a problem. We are just collecting information about the errors, then we will restart the computer".

There is a fsl folder in home/user but the "fsl" command is not recognized in the ubuntu terminal.

what should i do ? [screen of my terminal during FSL installation lag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVy43.png)

Comment: Is there a support group for the software?

Comment: Not as far as I know...